# How to define a function to use with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: numpy, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

> ```
> L*Q'' + R*Q' + (1/C)*Q = E(t), E(t) = 230*sin(50*t)
> ```

for Q(t) and Q'(t)

```
C = 0.0014 #F
dQ_0 = 2.6 #A
L = 1.8 #H
n = 575 #/
Q_0 = 1e-06 #C
R = 43 #Ohm
t_f = 2.8 #s

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

t = np.linspace(0, t_f, n)

def E(x):
    return 230*np.sin(50*x)

y = E(y)

def Q(t, y, R, L, C):
     return (y - L*Q'' - R*Q')*C

init_cond = [Q_0, dQ_0]

y_ivp = solve_ivp(Q, t_span=(0, t_f), y0=init_cond)
```

I am only trying to understand how to correctly define a function that is passed as an argument 'fun' in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Comment: where is the definition of your Q(t) function?

Comment: I was supposed to calculate Q(t) as a numpy.array like set of values, with initial conditions Q_0 and dQ_0 given at time t=0 and according to forementioned governing differential equation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below is no longer valid, `solve_ode` has since implemented the `args` parameter similar to `odeint`. So indeed

```
y_ivp = solve_ivp(Q, t_span=(0, t_f), y0=init_cond, args=(R, L, C))
```

is now valid (do not forget to set appropriate error tolerances, or at least check that the default values `arol=1e-3, rtol=1e-6` are appropriate).

Always available was the use of semi-global variables in a closure or lambda expression

```
y_ivp = solve_ivp(lambda t,y: Q(t,y,R, L, C), t_span=(0, t_f), y0=init_cond, args=(R, L, C))
```

---

*(obsolete part)* `solve_ivp` has no parameter passing mechanism, so treat the parameters as global variables. You are formulating an ODE for `Q`, as it is a second order ODE, the state also contains the first derivative, as you somehow recognized in the composition of the initial state. The ODE function then needs to produce the derivative values at a given state. Identify `Q(t)=Q[0]` and `Q'(t)=Q[1]`, then

```
def Q_ode(t, Q):
     return [ Q[1], (E(t) - R*Q[1] - (1/C)*Q[0])/L ]
```

I would continue to name the variables containing `Q` values with the letter `Q`.

Comment: The parameter passing mechanism for `solve_ivp` is well documented. See the Lotka-Volterra example here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

Comment: This was an addition that was demanded in bug reports or pull requests, but not yet implemented in the main version at the time of the answer.